# R web scraping of news site: how to pull main content

Tags: r, web-scraping

I have a code below. It goes to 3 distinct news pages and pulls their content. But for each page, I have to search for a different customized html tag.

1. Is there a way to get information from any news page by searching
   for only 1 tag? That will allow me to scrape information from many
   pages
2. How can i search for tags matching certain criteria: for
       example `html_nodes like ("#main*")` or `html_nodes like ("*main*")`

`library(MASS)     # base R`

```
library(XML)
library(xml2)
library(rvest)    # R web scraping


    # get the page using rvest fcns
    page2 <- read_html("http://seekingalpha.com/article/3974491-3-things-will-save-intels-future");

      page.all2 <- page2 %>%
      html_nodes("#main_container") %>%
      #html_nodes(class="*main*") %>%
      html_text()
     page.all2

    page5 <- read_html("http://www.fool.com/investing/general/2016/05/09/intel-corporations-strange-choice.aspx");
    page.all5 <- page5 %>%
      html_nodes("#article-1") %>%
      html_text()
      page.all5

    page1 <- read_html("http://www.valuewalk.com/2016/05/intel-no-2-explains-company-headed/ ");
    page.all1 <- page1 %>%
      html_nodes("#main") %>%
      html_text()
    page.all1

    # get a URL (1 URL per row in column link);
```

Comment: For all 3 sites you agree not to _"…use any robot, spider, site search/retrieval application, or other manual or automatic device or process to download, retrieve, index, "data mine", "scrape", "harvest" or in any way reproduce or circumvent the navigational structure or presentation of the Site or its contents;"_  ; _"…create abstracts from or scrape our Content,"_ ; _"Any other use of the Materials on this website, including any form of copying or reproduction … is strictly prohibited and is in violation of our proprietary rights."_ (just cuz you can doesn't mean you shld)

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
html <- '
<div class="pain">A</div>
<div class="pain">B</div>
<div class="mainer">C</div>
<div class="emainer">D</div>'
```

you can do for example

```
# all tags of class 'pain'
read_html(html) %>% xml_nodes(xpath="//*[@class='pain']")
# {xml_nodeset (2)}
# [1] <div class="pain">A</div>
# [2] <div class="pain">B</div>

# All DIV tags, where class names start with 'main'
read_html(html) %>% xml_nodes(xpath="//div[starts-with(@class, 'main')]")
# {xml_nodeset (1)}
# [1] <div class="mainer">C</div>

# All DIV tags, where class names contain 'main'
read_html(html) %>% xml_nodes(xpath="//div[contains(@class, 'main')]")
# {xml_nodeset (2)}
# [1] <div class="mainer">C</div>
# [2] <div class="emainer">D</div>
```

Comment: That answers my 2nd question. Anything about the 1st? I have thousands of pages and I wont be able to search each of them for the correct html tag...is there any `universal html tag` that will return page content for all the pages?

Comment: No, there's no "univsersal html tag". FWIW, you can get the whole content with `read_html(html) %>% html_text`.

Comment: is there a way to copy conten/output of `read_html(html) %>% xml_nodes(xpath="//*[@class='pain']")` in a variable?

Comment: `read_html(html) %>% xml_nodes(xpath="//*[@class='pain']") %>% html_text -> myvariable`?

Comment: that works. But would it be possible to show how to use it in the code that I have shown above? I tried `read_html(page2) %>% xml_nodes(xpath="//*[@class='#main_container']") %>% html_text -> myvariable` but got the error ' no applicable method for 'read_xml' applied to an object of class "c('xml_document', 'xml_node')"'

Comment: `read_html("http://seekingalpha.com/article/3974491-3-things-will-save-intels-future") %>% xml_nodes(xpath="//*[@class='main_container']") %>% html_text -> myvariable`, if there is a class named `main_container`, you should get its content in `myvariable`

Comment: I am thinking of searching for all html  tags using command like below. `read_html("http://seekingalpha.com/article/3974491-3-things-will-save-intels-future") %>% xml_nodes(xpath="//div[contains(@class, 'a')]") %>% html_text -> myvariable `. My plan is that i will replace `a ` in `(@class, 'a')` with all characters from b to z so that I can pull all the tags. Then as `myvariable ` is a list, I will take the list element that has maximum length and probably that would contain the main article...does it seem feasible? how can i search for all html tags? I already tried on few pages and it works!

Comment: You are pulling all div tags which have a class that contains the letter a. Please read through an introduction to xpath expressions, first: https://www.google.com/?q=xpath+basics